# JOINING table in oracle SQL

Tags: php, sql, oracle

**I am having problem on an attempt to join two tables in oracle and showing the value.**

What my code looks like this:

```
 if ($_POST['action'] == 'show'){
        
        $requestCompSql = "SELECT REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.PROJECT_NAME, 
                                  REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.BASE_PLATE, 
                                  REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.THICKNESS, 
                                    COMPONENT.CUTTING.QTY_REQUIRED,
                                  REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.QTY_REQUESTED
                                  REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.REQUESTER, 
                                  REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.REQUEST_DATE 
                                        FROM REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING
                                        INNER JOIN COMPONENT_CUTTING
                                  ON REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.PROJECT_NAME = COMPONENT_CUTTING.PROJECT_NAME
                                    AND REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.THICKNESS = COMPONENT_CUTTING.THICKNESS
                                    AND REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.BASE_PLATE = COMPONENT_CUTTING.BASE_PLATE = '{$_POST["bp"]}'";

        $requestCompParse = oci_parse($conn, $requestCompSql);

        oci_execute($requestCompParse);

        while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($requestCompParse)){
        
        echo "<div class='table-responsive'>";
        echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
                                echo '<table cellspacing = "0"';
                                    echo '<thead>';
                                    echo '<tr>
                                              <th>PROJECT</th>
                                              <th>BASEPLATE</th>
                                              <th>THICK</th>
                                              <th>QTY REQUESTED</th>
                                              <th>QTY REQUIRED</th>
                                              <th>REQUESTER</th>
                                              <th>REQ. DATE</th>
                                              <th align="center">ACTION</th>  
                                          </tr>
                                          </thead>';

                                     echo "<tbody>";
                                        echo "<tr class='warning'><td>$row[PROJECT_NAME]</td>";
                                        echo "<td>$row[BASE_PLATE]</td>";
                                        echo "<td>$row[THICKNESS]</td>";
                                        echo "<td>$row[QTY_REQUESTED]</td>";
                                        echo "<td>$row[QTY_REQUIRED]</td>";
                                        echo "<td>$row[REQUESTER]</td>";
                                        echo "<td>$row[REQUEST_DATE]</td>";
                                        echo "<td><input type='button' value='OK' class='btn btn-success'>
                                            <input type='button' value='REJECT' class='btn btn-danger'></td>";

                                        echo "</tr>";
                                     echo "</tbody>";
                                 echo "<table cellspacing = '0'";
                                 echo "</div>";
        }

    }
```

and the error message given is like this:

> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\Component_approval\show_requested_component.php on line 60
>
> Warning: oci_fetch_assoc(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\Component_approval\show_requested_component.php on line 62

I've been so frustrated with this because the `QTY_REQUIRED` value must be based on `PROJECT_NAME`, `THICKNESS` and `BASE_PLATE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put `WHERE`, 1 COMMA is missing and irregular three way comparation. Try it like this:

```
 $requestCompSql = "SELECT REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.PROJECT_NAME, 
                                      REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.BASE_PLATE, 
                                      REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.THICKNESS, 
                                        COMPONENT.CUTTING.QTY_REQUIRED,
                                      REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.QTY_REQUESTED,
                                      REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.REQUESTER, 
                                      REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.REQUEST_DATE 
                                            FROM REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING
                                            INNER JOIN COMPONENT_CUTTING
                                      ON REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.PROJECT_NAME = COMPONENT_CUTTING.PROJECT_NAME
                                        WHERE REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.THICKNESS = COMPONENT_CUTTING.THICKNESS
                                        AND REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.BASE_PLATE = COMPONENT_CUTTING.BASE_PLATE
                                        AND COMPONENT_CUTTING.BASE_PLATE = '{$_POST["bp"]}'";
```

Comment: I do it like this but it doesnt work either 

[link](http://pastebin.com/GqR51P1g)

Answer (score 4):

The last line of the `where` clause is:

```
AND REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.BASE_PLATE = COMPONENT_CUTTING.BASE_PLATE = '{$_POST["bp"]}'
```

You should split this into two different conditions:

```
AND REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.BASE_PLATE = COMPONENT_CUTTING.BASE_PLATE
AND COMPONENT_CUTTING.BASE_PLATE = '{$_POST["bp"]}'
```

Also, you are missing a comma in the `select` and need to replace a period with an underscore:

```
                       SELECT REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.PROJECT_NAME, 
                              REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.BASE_PLATE, 
                              REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.THICKNESS, 
                                COMPONENT_CUTTING.QTY_REQUIRED,
-----------------------------------------^
                              REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.QTY_REQUESTED,
---------------------------------------------------------------------^
                              REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.REQUESTER, 
                              REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.REQUEST_DATE
```

Comment: It's also worth mentioning looking into [binding query variables](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) rather than inserting them directly from $_POST to your query string to protect you from malicious attacks and side effects such as [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Very simple way to secure your database interactions.

Comment: @Alex.Ritna I am aware of that but when i got this one working, ill start to bind everything :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff its still doesnt work tho,

Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00904: "COMPONENT"."CUTTING"."QTY_REQUIRED": invalid identifier in C:\xampp\htdocs\WeltesInformationCenter\Component_approval\show_requested_component.php on line 61

Comment: @Chriskonz that's because `COMPONENT.CUTTING.QTY_REQUIRED` doesn't exist as an object in the database. Perhaps you meant to put `COMPONENT_CUTTING.QTY_REQUIRED` (with an underscore _)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I can see two issues in your query

1, a comma ',' is missing after on line 5

> REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.QTY_REQUESTED
>   REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.REQUESTER,

2, the condition is not correctly implemented at last line

> AND REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.BASE_PLATE = COMPONENT_CUTTING.BASE_PLATE = '{$_POST["bp"]}'

this could be

> AND REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.BASE_PLATE = COMPONENT_CUTTING.BASE_PLATE 
>   AND COMPONENT_CUTTING.BASE_PLATE = '{$_POST["bp"]}'"

above is just a guess, you may correct based on your requirement.

Comment: I think the quotes could also have an issue = '{$_POST["bp"]}'" change it to = ' " . {$_POST["bp"]} . " ' ";